# Choosing Keyboard type destroys returning to main screen by "done"

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to show different keyboardtypes when user clicks on specific uitextfields, I can do that but then I lose the ability to hide the keyboard while pressing the "done" button.

Is there a specific place and way that I should define the keyboard type? `viewDidload`? or for example just when `editingDidBegin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your keyboard type right after you `alloc`/`init` your `UITextField`.  You can also do this in Interface Builder, if you have your views set up there.

Make sure you are implementing the `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:` method and setting your delegates accordingly.

Also, any fields using a numeric keyboard will not show the Done button, so there is no direct way to dismiss the keyboard.  I've found that setting my background `view` as a `UIControl` and implementing a method to dismiss my keyboard upon any background taps has been quite useful.

EDIT:
In Interface Builder, change the class of your view from `UIView` to `UIControl`.  Then, implement a method to pick up any taps on the background, mine for example:

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap
{
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Then, connect this `IBAction` to the `UIControl` (drag to anywhere in the background) in Interface Builder.  Now, any tap on the background should call this method and resign all textFields as FirstResponder.

Comment: can you explain how did you this? "setting my background view as a UIControl and implementing a method to dismiss my keyboard upon any background taps has been quite useful."